# numpy cond wrong output

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a `1000 by 5000` matrix `A`. I'm trying to find its condition number. I know the condition number to be the ratio between the largest and smallest eigenvalues of `A.T @ A` but maybe I'm wrong so I checked the other way around as well.

I wrote the following script:

```
print(np.linalg.cond(A))
eig = np.linalg.eig(A.T @ A)[0]
print(eig[0] / eig[-1])
eig = np.linalg.eig(A @ A.T)[0]
print(eig[0] / eig[-1])
```

and it prints

```
1549.2730284204385
(5.3052933708830795e+20+0j)
1076234.004648219
```

Can anyone explain the discrepancy?

Comment: You want to use the singular values, i.e. the square roots of the non-negative eigenvalues of A.T@A, right? For example the singular values obtained with `linalg.svd` give you this behaviour and `linalg.cond(A)=linalg.svd(A)[1][0]/linalg.svd(A)[1][-1]`

Answer (score 1):

The condition number is the ratio between the largest and smallest singular values, which are the square roots of the eigenvalues of `A.T@A`. You can compute the singular values with the SVD and they will be already sorted.

```
S = np.linalg.svd(A,compute_uv=False)
print(S[0] / S[-1])
```

If you want to use the eigenvalues then you have to sort them yourself.

```
vals = np.sort(np.linalg.eigvals(A.T@A))
print(np.sqrt(vals[-1]) / np.sqrt(vals[0]))
```